# Why is there no error in PHP if you try to use brackets to get the value of a key on a NULL?

Tags: php, null, dereference

I tried the following code in both facebook's phpsh and the standard crappy php -a abomination for a repl:

```
$a = NULL;
echo $a['foobar'];
```

To my regret (I wouldn't call it surprise or disappointment when it concerns PHP) I don't get any errors or warnings or exceptions or anything.

Smarter languages like Ruby and Python both complain when trying to dereference a key from eg None or nil. How is PHP interpreting this situation? Is the only cure inserting is_null checks everywhere? Should I blame Smarty for not doing it for me?

Comment: You won't get errors or exceptions either way, in this case it would probably be a notice, and for many reasons, notices are hidden by default. Not that I agree with it, Joomla, as an example, has a lot of unreliable and flawed code because it was developed and tested on such systems.

Comment: This case doesn't even generate an `E_NOTICE`, so error_reporting won't help here.

Comment: If you do $a = array('php' => 'sucks so bad'); $a['foobar'] in php -a you get a notice at least. Which is kind of crappy for serious code but at least it give you something.

Comment: That's interesting. At first, I thought it should generate E_NOTICE, then tried the code... Hmmmmmmm

Comment: I've amended my answer to try and redeem myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to PHP source code (`Zend/zend_execute.c`), only strings, arrays and objects can trigger errors when accessing an offset/index. The rest is more-or-less ignored:

```
$a = true;
$b = false;
$c = null;
$d = 1;
$e = 1.234;
$f = '';
$g = array();
$h = new stdClass;

echo $a[0]; // NULL
echo $b[0]; // NULL
echo $c[0]; // NULL
echo $d[0]; // NULL
echo $e[0]; // NULL
echo $f[0]; // E_NOTICE: Uninitialized string offset
echo $g[0]; // E_NOTICE: Undefined offset
echo $h[0]; // E_FATAL:  Cannot use object as array
```

None of `$a`,`$b`,`$c`,`$d` or `$e` actually spit an error. Most of the times in the code I just see `return;` or `return 0;`, which means NULL,  instead of a returned `zval*` (pointer) or `zend_error()` call. Hence the results above.

Whatever the reason why it has been done like this, it doesn't really matter. You should always check a variable for existence and/or nullity in such cases. The safest ways (slightly different behaviours) are `isset` and `empty`:

```
isset($a['foo']);
!empty($a['foo']);
```

Comment: Does the lack of errors seem to be a result of laziness or just PHP's general philosophy of rather doing something, even if it's not useful, than "annoying" the programmer with errors and exceptions and all that nasty stuff?

Comment: @Sam: It most certainly isn't laziness. Probable that a simple `zend_error` call would have done the trick. It may have something to do with the fact that `isset($a['foo'])` would spit an error is `$a` is a null, an int, etc. making you have to do like `isset($a) && isset($a['foo'])`. That would be annoying. I guess I could try to modify the code and see what happens. ;-)